# angular Orderby Date not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have some json data I get from my server that has a date field formatted like "StartDateTime":"2014-09-04T18:14:26Z"

i create a table as follows:

```
 <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover responsive">
    <tr><th>Title</th><th>Start Date</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="eachEvent in Events | orderBy:StartDateTime">
      <td><span>{{eachEvent.Title}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{eachEvent.StartDateTime|date:'short'}}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

the events are not ordered correctly by the start date. My question is what do I need to do to get this date to sort correctly. Fyi, not included in my example is clicking on the column to sort by date and reverse it. When I do this the dates are sorted correctly. So what I need is the initial sort to be done correctly.

here is a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECrAlBgWOMQzEzdfmq6j)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply missing quotes around `StartDateTime`. The following works in your example.

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachEvent in Events | orderBy:'StartDateTime'">
```